# import class from another/folder into views, django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am making a scraper function with tidy folder structure. But when I try to import scraper `class` into views.py it's giving an error:

> 'module' object is not callable

This is the Tree:

```
├── api_services
│   ├── spiders
│   │   ├── spiderAtom.py
│   │   └── spiderEbis.py
│   └── views
│       └── viewApi.py
```

In spiders folder I have this `class`:

```
class spiderAtom:
    def atom():    
        string = "return this method"    
        return string
```

and trying import it in `viewApi`

```
from ..spiders import spiderAtom

def atomApi(request): 

    spider = spiderAtom()
    response = spider.atom()

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

But with the the way I am doing is not working.

Comment: According to your import statement, you should try this `spider 
 = spiderAtom.spiderAtom()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `__init__.py` file to `api_services` and then call `from api_services.spiders.spiderAtom import spiderAtom`.

Comment: Of course there is already `__init__py` file in **api_services** but not effective.

Comment: So try `from api_services.spiders.spiderAtom import spiderAtom`

Comment: oh, it worked out with this import way. but why not the former import is not worked out? do you have any idea about that? could you explain a bit?

Comment: I believe, this article can explain it clearly than me) https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/